# Pandas looping through rows check if one column row is empty and another is not

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below output that I place into a df. Now I want to loop through each row and check if the `comment` col. is not empty and if `status` col is empty.
The 'yes' should print out once because the df only has 1 that meets these requirements but it print out twice:

```
output = [['table_name', 'schema_name', 'column_name', 'data_type', 'null?', 'default', 'kind', 'expression', 'comment', 'database_name', 'autoincrement', 'Status'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_DATETIME', '{"type":"TIMESTAMP_LTZ","precision":0,"scale":9,"nullable":true}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', 'date and time when table was loaded', 'DEV'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_FILENAME', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'DEV']]

output = filter(bool, output)


df = pd.DataFrame(output)

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]


query_list = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Status'] is None and row['comment'] is not None or row['comment'] != '':
        print('yes')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is incorrect. You should have

```
if row['Status'] is None and row['comment'] is not None and row['comment'] != '':
```

On another note, we can obtain this row via boolean indexing:

```
df[~df.loc[:,'comment'].isin(['',None])]
```

returns

|  | table_name | schema_name | column_name | data_type | null? | default | kind | expression | comment | database_name | autoincrement | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACCOUNT | SO | _LOAD_DATETIME | {"type":"TIMESTAMP_LTZ","precision":0,"scale":9,"nullable":true} | TRUE |  | COLUMN |  | date and time when table was loaded | DEV |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

Your condition starts as

```
if row['Status'] is None and row['comment'] is not None...
```

and if you look at "Status" column, it is:

```
1    None
2    None
Name: Status, dtype: object
```

so the if-condition is True twice.

If you want to show filter only the rows where "Comment is not empty and Status is empty", then you could use a boolean mask using bitwise & operator:

```
msk = df['Status'].isna() & df['comment'].ne('')
out = df[msk]
```

Comment: but there is only 1 comment so I want it to show only when both conditions are met. Comment is not empty and Status is empty.

Comment: @KristiLuna please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can create boolean indexing ahead of time by comparing scalars against the entire column. It fits pandas a little more stylistically I think and is pretty readable. Then these conditions which contain the valid indexes desired can be applied to the DataFrame before the loop.

```
status_none = pd.isnull(df['Status'])
comment_not_empty = ~(df['comment'] == '')

for index, row in df[status_none & comment_not_empty ].iterrows():
    print('yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben is right, but you can check if it the field have or dont have any value like this:

```
if not row['Status'] and row['comment']:
```