# Optimizing Python Code: String Assignment from List

Tags: python

I have a CSV file and I read the contents. I need to verify that every element of each row is not empty:

```
fname = row[0]
if fname is None:
    flag = -1
lname = row[1]
if lname is None:
    flag = -1
phone = row[2]
if phone is None:
    flag = -1
email = row[3]
if email is None:
    flag = -1
[...]
```

Is there a way to optimize this code? Is there a way to do something like this in Python:

```
fname = row[0] if None else flag = -1 ?
[...]
```

At the end I will check if flag is -1, I send an error notification (because this is a background task)

Comment: You could check if any of those values are None in a  single statement at the end.

Comment: You can submit your answer please :) Thank you.

Comment: you can use pandas to check if any row of any column has null value check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71116935/pandas-looping-through-rows-check-if-one-column-row-is-empty-and-another-is-not

Comment: `if None in (fname, lname, phone, email): flag = -1`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson That works well if it's only 4 columns.  Not so good if the csv file has 400, or it's variable.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety: True but you don't want to do 400 `foo = row[n]` assignments either. Here are a couple more possibilities: `fname, lname, phone, email = field_vals = row[:4]; if None in field_vals: ...` or `if None in row[start:end]: ...` depending on what you're dealing with. Part of my assumption is that there are other fields in addition to what the OP posted (much as your assumption that there might be 400 - but perhaps only four are of interest at the moment - hence the individual assignments of the OP).

Answer (score 1):

```
if all([len(e) for e in row]):
    # Row is good
else:
    # Row is bad
```

We can't just do `all(row)` because there may be a non-empty but falsey value.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```py
with open('testdata1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in csv_reader:
    if not row[0]:
         continue  # this will skip to the next for loop iteration
    # do your processing here
```

Found it at https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/python-csv-row-index-is-empty-with-code-examples/

Comment: But what if row[5] is empty? That's the question, every field should be checked individually, my code actually works, I just wanted to optimize it a bit.